# CNN-lstm on keras and theano produces unsuall error

Tags: python

until yesterday i was able to compile the following code. I was using theano 0.8.0 and keras 1. i update them both to the lastest version and for this simple test network

```
model = Sequential()   
model.add(Embedding(max_features, embedding_size, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                    filter_length=filter_length,
                    border_mode='valid',
                    activation='relu',
                    subsample_length=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=pool_length))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_output_size))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])`
```

I am getting the following error :

```
BlockquoteTraceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/usera/Desktop/2/fgdgfgf.py", line 73, in <module> validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 620, in fit sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1104, in fit callback_metrics=callback_metrics)
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 822, in _fit_loop outs = f(ins_batch)
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 672, in __call__ return self.function(*inputs)
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 871, in __call__ storage_map=getattr(self.fn, 'storage_map', None))
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 314, in raise_with_op reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_trace)
File "C:\Users\usera\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 859, in __call__ outputs = self.fn()
MemoryError: alloc failed
Apply node that caused the error: Alloc(TensorConstant{(1L, 1L, 1L) of 0.0}, TensorConstant{24}, Elemwise{Composite{((i0 * i1) // i2)}}[(0, 0)].0, TensorConstant{280})
Toposort index: 145
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, (True, True, True)), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar), TensorType(int64, scalar)]
Inputs shapes: [(1L, 1L, 1L), (), (), ()]
Inputs strides: [(4L, 4L, 4L), (), (), ()]
Inputs values: [array([[[ 0.]]], dtype=float32), array(24L, dtype=int64), array(-450L, dtype=int64), array(280L, dtype=int64)]
Outputs clients: [[IncSubtensor{Inc;:int64:}(Alloc.0, Subtensor{::int64}.0, Constant{24}), IncSubtensor{InplaceInc;int64::}(Alloc.0, IncSubtensor{Inc;:int64:}.0, Constant{0}), forall_inplace,cpu,grad_of_scan_fn}(TensorConstant{24}, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Elemwise{tanh}.0, Alloc.0, Elemwise{Composite{(i0 - sqr(i1))}}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int64}.0, Alloc.0, Alloc.0, TensorConstant{24}, TensorConstant{24}, TensorConstant{24}, TensorConstant{24}, TensorConstant{24}, lstm_1_U_o, lstm_1_U_f, lstm_1_U_i, lstm_1_U_c, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0, InplaceDimShuffle{1,0}.0)]]
```

HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with by setting the Theano flag `optimizer=fast_compile`. If that does not work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with `optimizer=None`.

HINT: Use the Theano flag `exception_verbosity=high` for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

Process finished with exit code 1

Any idea why this was working with previous version but is not working on theano 0.8.2?

Comment: `MemoryError: alloc failed` are you sure you have enough RAM?

Comment: I'm running on a 64gb ram machine. The size of the dataset is not that big in order my pc to run out of memory. Being not able to produce a solution i  downgrade my libraries and the problem solved..